# Find a list of files from text file in subdirectories and put into tarball?

Tags: bash, unix, archiving, tar

I have a list of files I need to tar.  Typically, I would use

`tar -cvf allfiles.tar -T mylist.txt`

But I discovered that the files I need are scattered into subdirectories and my list only has the file names not the paths.

Is there a way to combine "find" with the tar command to find the files on my list wherever they are filed in subdirectories?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can find the paths using your list of names and `find`, but you may be caught by a little corner case, given when you have the files with the same name in different directories.

If it does not really matter, you can do the following:

```
find <main_directory> | grep -f mylist.txt
```

And then, use the list to your `tar` command. The complete command may look like:

```
tar cvf allfiles.tar -T <(find <main_directory> |
    grep -f mylist.txt --color=never)
```

Notice you **must** use `--color=never`, otherwise, if colors are active for your grep, you'd be sending invalid input for `tar`.

To ignore case distinctions, in this case, in `grep`, which is the one actually **filtering** files, you can simply add the flag `-i`:

```
tar cvf allfiles.tar -T <(find <main_directory> |
    grep -i -f mylist.txt --color=never)
```

Comment: Makes sense.  Is there any way to tell tar to parse the list case-insensitive?  People weren't very careful with directory naming since this is a windows server.

Comment: @Steve see if the last command line works for you.

Comment: What does the < do before the (find...)?

Comment: @Steve when you execute a command, bracing it with `<()`, you're telling the shell to consider the output of the command being executed as a file itself, and it returns you a file descriptor -- which is, then,  given as the `<file>` parameter to `tar ... -T <file>`. Please, notice the line break is simply in order to avoid the scroll bar up there; there's no line break in the command itself.